# SQLAlchemy: Broken op() in filter() with IntEnum?

Tags: python-3.x, enums, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to implement an access system for users inspired by the unix-style rwx bits using SQLAlchemy on MySQL. For readability, I decided to use a python `enum.IntEnum` for the values (1, 2, 4). Storing them in a `SmallInteger` Column also seems to work as expected.

However, to filter out matching access rights, I'm using a filter expression like

```
.filter(Access.mode.op('&')(AccessMode.WRITE) == AccessMode.WRITE)
```

where `AccessMode` is an `IntEnum` subclass and `mode` the `SmallInteger` Column. In this case, SQLAlchemy crashes with

```
AttributeError: 'AccessMode' object has no attribute 'translate'
```

which I don't quite understand because I assumed an `IntEnum` attribute would (mostly) always behave like an actual `int`.

To try out what happens, I implemented a `translate()` method for this type which just returns `str(self).translate(...)`. Now SQLAlchemy throws no error, but also does not apply the intended filtering on the result (which I totally accept since I have no idea of the internal algorithms applied).

A workaround would be to manually cast everything to `int`, but that's not quite nice. Does anybody have an idea how to do this in a better way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error is pymysql tripping on the enum object, since it has no converter for it. Use `AccessMode.WRITE.value`.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly! :) I'll accept it as answer if you'd like to answer it.
But I don't get how pymysql can even distinguish an IntEnum from an int since isinstance returns True?